# How can I edit my environment so that 'ls **/*.js' doesn't result in an 'argument list too long' error?

Tags: bash, macos, unix, command-line

I am working through a react tutorial that is using eslint. When I type:

```
eslint **/*.js
```

it returns 'argument list too long' when I run from the project root. The following works, but does not include all the files.

```
eslint **/*.js
```

The problem, however, is not eslint, as the following results in the same error.

```
ls **/*.js
```

and

```
ls */*.js
```

This is not a big project and the only folder with a number of folders in it is the node_modules folder.

Why is it giving this error for a relatively small area and is there a way to capture all js files in the folder and subfolders?

Comment: If you're getting this with a small number of files (and not-exceptionally-long file/directory names), chances are you've `export`ed a ton of cruft to your environment. Environment variables and command-line arguments live in the same space.

Comment: ...look through the output of `env`, and figure out what doesn't need to be there. (If a variable doesn't need to be accessible to subprocesses, then you can set it as a regular shell variable without exporting it!)

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
printf '%s\0' **/*.js | xargs -0 eslint
```

...or...

```
find . -name '*.js' -exec eslist {} +
```

...will run a larger number of `eslint` invocations, each having only as many arguments as will fit on a single invocation's command line.

Comment: Flagged community-wiki to avoid harvesting rep from answering a known dupe.